# discord.py set_image onto embed doesn't work

Tags: image, discord.py

I'm trying to set an image on an embed called `image.png` and this is my code
`file = discord.File("[IMAGEPATHFILE]", filename="image.png")`

```
def returnEmbed() -> discord.Embed:
    return discord.Embed(
            title = formatData['name'],
            description = descrpt,
            color = discord.Color(value=int(formatData['colorHEX'], 16))
        ).set_thumbnail(url = 'attachment://image.png')
```

(in main.py):

```
await message.channel.send(embed = returnEmbed())
```

The actual embed itself works, but the image just doesn't pop up. `image.png` is a valid PNG, and online pictures work, but all the local files just don't work.

Plz help

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the file by doing

```
await message.channel.send(embed=returnEmbed(), file=file)
```

##### Solution

```
def return_embed() -> discord.Embed:

    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://image.png")

# ...
file = discord.File("[IMAGEPATHFILE]", filename="image.png")
await message.channel.send(embed=returnEmbed(), file=file)
```

Comment: puncher I'm not trying to send the actual file, rather trying to send it as the image for an embed. The reason why I'm defining the variable "file" was because it was in another question and it worked for them but thanks anyway.

Comment: With that, you won't send the file as a file when you use it in combination with `.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://image.png")`. It will send the image via the thumbnail of the embed.

Comment: yes, which I have tried using both .set_thumbnail and .set_image, with correct syntax